# VB Datagrid Get New Value

Tags: vb.net

Now I want to get the new value what I put into my datagrid; however, I always get the old value if I keys Up or Down.

Here is my KeyDownEvent Function:

```
Private Sub grd_MyGridKeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles grd.MyGridKeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
            Me.grd.Item(Me.grd.CurrentRowIndex, 4) = Me.grd.Item(Me.grd.CurrentRowIndex, 2) * Me.grd.Item(Me.grd.CurrentRowIndex, 3)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean by **if I keys Up or Down.** ?

Comment: 「↑」or「↓」, Sorry about my poor English

Comment: If the currentrowindex is 2, then I keys Up to 1 or keys Down to 3, but when it changes rows, value of column 4 does not change.

Comment: When I use breakpoint to see my value in CurrentCellChanged Event, the value is the old value not what I put in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution in Japanese website, so I just post what I used to solve my problem.

`Me.grd.Item(Me.grd.CurrentRowIndex, 3) = DirectCast(ColumnMoney, DataGridTextBoxColumn).TextBox.Text`

`grd` is my `datagrid`, and this is the solution. Hope that this will help others who also meet this problem.

Answer (score 0):

On your datagridview CellValidating Event

```
e.Cancel = False
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I use datagrid not datagridview.

Comment: @Neolisk http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=VS.95).aspx

Comment: @CYB: So your question is about Silverlight? I am almost sure everybody assumed WinForms.

Comment: Nope, my question is about WinForms. Sorry that I didn't change the version to .NetFramework

Comment: @CYB: The link you provided is about Silverlight. Please use correct tags regardless. If you solved your problem, please feel free to post your own answer and then accept it when you are allowed to (48 hours after posting). Also please do quote a person who you are replying to. Otherwise they don't get notified.